# Text Search prevent reload all data in tableview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

There is one uitextview and uitableview and this tableview fetch all the data. If i search the text in uitextview it fetches the result (whatever i type on uitextview) but problem is after getting the search result and i scroll down a little bit then the table reloads/ again fetches all the data under search result. How to prevent the reload data if i scroll down after text search?

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtSearch: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tblAllRest: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var ScrollViewMain: UIScrollView!
var arrayAllRest : [HomeRestaurantModel] = []
var page = 1
self.tblAllRest.delegate = self
        self.tblAllRest.dataSource = self
self.txtSearch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.txtChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
@objc func txtChanged(_ sender : UITextField){
        self.page = 1
        self.getRestData()
    }
func getRestData(){ // api call
        GFunctions.shared.APICallRestaurantSearchList(tbl : self.tblAllRest ,page: self.page.description, is_featured: "All", search: self.txtSearch.text!) { (complete, arrayRest) in
            if complete{
                if self.page == 1{
                    self.arrayAllRest = arrayRest
                }else{
                    self.arrayAllRest += arrayRest
                }
            }else{
                if self.page == 1{
                    self.arrayAllRest = []
                }
            }
            self.page += 1
            self.tblAllRest.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code – by the way it doesn't compile – doesn't indicate that it refetches data on scrolling

Comment: Is that `UITextField` inside `UITableView` as a cell?

Comment: @TomasJablonskis Actually i am a beginner in swift

Comment: @TomasJablonskis I can able to search the text and i get the result on tableview but if i scroll down it reloads all data

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a boolean variable, let's say `isSearched`, and make it true whenever the search is made.

And then in you function `getRestData`, check if isSearched is true, and if it is just return from the function, otherwise load the data is `isSearched` is false

Comment: @ Vikash Lal Dodani Could you please where i put the condition?Because i try to put the conditions still it is not working
`func getRestData(){let isSearched = true
GFunctions.shared.APICallRestaurantSearchList(tbl : self.tblAllRest as? TblEmptyMessage,page: self.page.description, is_featured: "All", search: self.txtSearch.text!) { (complete, arrayRest) in
if complete{
if (isSearched == true){self.arrayAllRest = arrayRest}else{
self.arrayAllRest += arrayRest}}else{
self.arrayAllRest = []}}else{if self.page == 1{
self.arrayAllRest = []}}
self.page += 1
self.tblAllRest.reloadData()}}`